# Django saving to public media folder , error 403

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

So i have `Angular` + `Django REST API` applications hosted on `nginx` + `gunicorn` setup.
I'm facing a weird problem . I have my media folder permisssions set to `777` and in my nginx config:

```
location /media  {
     alias /home/shalin95/zona_project/zona_api/media;
     expires 20m;
}
```

I have a model `Product` with `main_picture` field ( `ImageField` saving the files to `/media/photos/`) .
When i create new instance ( new product ), and sometimes when i want to open the image in the browser i get `403 Forbidden` error.

NOTE: This happens occasionally , not on every instance saved ( no specific pattern , just randomly)

Thank if i go and `chmod -R 777` the media folder everything is okay ( i can see the picture ) , but why this happens  ( on some occasions ) ?

Comment: Should'nt you be using `root` instead of `alias`?
Try doing this: `root  /home/shalin95/zona_project/zona_api`

Comment: Is this really the issue solving ? I've seen the difference `alias` vs `root` https://innopy.wordpress.com/2016/01/18/nginx-static-file-serving-confusion-with-root-alias/ , does this have any value here ?

Comment: Does Ngnix has separate user? Can you make acl for Nginix (user) on that dir? Then make acl default, so everytime new file is created ngnix will have access to it. And what is your distro?

Comment: Hi, sorry for late response. The user is `www-data` and i'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Does maybe `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data media` solve the issue ?

Answer (score 2):

So i've concluded that this issue only occurs only when the request was larger than ( ~ 4MB ) i think , so i've added

```
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 100000000
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS  = 0o644
```

in the `settings.py` file and now the uploads work okay.